# How to fill an array with specific random numbers (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have to fill 1 row of an multidimensional array with integers going from 1 to 3 completely random.
Example: if I would print that row it **could** give : 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 3

Now to do this i thought following code would work:

```
private void fillArray()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
         PincodeRandom[0][i]=i;
         PincodeRandom[1][i]= (int)Math.random()*3 +1;
        }
    }
```

however this results into filling the entire second row with only 1 (random) integer. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: obligatory [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: You are right i messed up simple math... 
The result of programming all day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(int)` will cast `Math.random()` to 0 before you multiply by 3, resulting in `0 * 3 + 1` which is always 1. Try:

```
(int)(Math.random()*3) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the `Random` class, make sure you create an instance **outside** of the loop, since `new Random()` uses the system time as a seed. So if two randoms are created during the same tick, they will produce the same random number sequence.

```
private void fillArray()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
     PincodeRandom[0][i]=i;
     PincodeRandom[1][i]= rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
 Random r = new Random();
for(loop){
    PincodeRandom[1][i]= = r.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random; 


public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] array = new int[2][10];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
     array[0][i]=i;
     array[1][i]= (int)rand.nextInt(3) +1;
    }
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(array[1][j]));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because (int)Math.random() is causing it to equal 0, since Math.random() is a double always inbetween 0 and 1.

Instead, import the java.util.Random class.

And use it like:
    new Random().nextInt(2)+1

Comment: But don't do exactly that as the seed is generally computed based on system time and this is in a tight loop.

Comment: Or at least put parens around `Math.random()*3` before applying `(int)`.

Comment: Yep, as @clcto says, don't create a new Random with each iteration, just apply `nextInt` to one created outside of the loop.

Comment: Yeah I know, I should probably have done that. Sorry